# PHP mysqli - using result of DELETE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and mysql, and I wonder if there is a way to use the result after a DELETE query.

For example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $someID);
$stmt->execute();
//Here I want to use the name of the deleted user.
```

I know I can make a SELECT query before deleting, I just wonder if there is a smart way to get the deleted row. All I found so far is

```
$stmt->affected_rows
```

but that only gives the number of affected rows.

Thanks

Comment: You can't get any deleted row data after deleting. You need to get data before deleting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DELETE` query deletes the data. It does not fetch the data. In fact, afterwards there's no data to fetch since it's been deleted. There is no "result" of a `DELETE` query.

`SELECT` the data before deleting if you need it.